# Launching App upon tapping Today Widget

Tags: swift

I have just added a today widget to my app and I am trying to allow users to tap on the widget to launch it's containing app.

Basically at the moment I have a button over the top of my widget which is linked to this function:

```
    @IBAction func launchApp(sender: AnyObject) {
    var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("AppName://home")
    self.extensionContext.openURL(url, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

When I run the app and tap on the widget I get an alert view that states:

Unsupported URL - This URL wasn't loaded: AppName://home

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does your app have a published URL scheme? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50

Comment: Ah! I had read about those way before I started learning to program for iOS. Didn't realise that that was what I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I've added that as an answer for you then. Glad it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To launch an app via URL you have to add a URL scheme to your app. The details of how to do that are found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

Comment: this is a really great step by step guide to creating a custom URL scheme: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html